# Фортран,устранить ошибки

Tags: fortran

что-то с условием не так,выдает ошибки:

```
C:\MSDEV\Projects\Text1.f90(17): error FOR3852: syntax error detected between ) and THEN
C:\MSDEV\Projects\Text1.f90(19): error FOR3563: ELSE without IF-THEN
C:\MSDEV\Projects\Text1.f90(21): error FOR3567: END IF without IF-THEN
C:\MSDEV\Projects\Text1.f90(26): warning FOR4270: unused symbol IF
C:\MSDEV\Projects\Text1.f90(26): error FOR2290: implicit type for IF
```

КАК ИСПРАВИТЬ?

```
program n5
implicit none
real x,y,x0,xk,dx,y0,yk,dy
integer j,i,imax,jmax
character l1*2,l2*2 
            print*,'vvedite x0,xk,dx i y0,yk,dy'
            read(*,*) x0,xk,dx,y0,yk,dy
            imax=((xk-x0)/dx+0.5)+1
            jmax=((yk-y0)/dy+0.5)+1
            l1=' *'
            l2=' .'

                do j=1,jmax
                    y=yk-(j-1)*dy
                        do i=1,imax
                            x=x0+(i-1)*dx
IF ((y.LE.exp(-x**2).AND.(y.GE.0).AND.(x.LE.1/sqrt(2).AND.(x.GE.-1/sqrt(2)) THEN
  print "(A,\)",l1
ELSE
  print "(A,\)",l2
end if
                        end do
print "(A,/)"       
                end do          
pause
end program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего не могу сказать про Фортран, но у вас в этой строке

```
((y.LE.exp(-x**2).AND.(y.GE.0).AND.(x.LE.1/sqrt(2).AND.(x.GE.-1/sqrt(2))
```

явно не достает 3х закрывающих скобок (*syntax error detected between ) and THEN*), что приводит к некорректности всей конструкции (*ELSE without IF-THEN*)

Вероятно, должно быть что-тов духе:

```
((y.LE.exp(-x**2).AND.(y.GE.0).AND.(x.LE.1/sqrt(2)).AND.(x.GE.-1/sqrt(2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

А что значит вот это вот?

```
  print "(A,\)",l1
```

А if-then-else -- так может у Вас формат программы кривой, и транслятор операторов не видит?